# How to retrieve the size of the Azure Recovery Services Backup Storage Vault in Azure Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am currently working on an Azure Powershell Script that retrieves the names of the Recovery Service Vaults, the protected VMs, as well as the current size of the vault.

However, I am unable to retrieve from Powershell the current size of the vault that stores the backups, which is available on the Azure portal (see attached image for easier reference to what data I would like to extract).

Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProperty only gives the BackupStorageRedundancy Property, but not the size. Neither the vault data (Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault), the storage context (Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext), the backup container (Get-AzureRmRecoveryBackupContainer), nor the backup item (Get-AzureRmRecoveryBackupItem) seems to have the size property I need.

Is this option implemented in Azure Powershell yet? If yes, which cmdlet gives me access to this data? If not, when will this be implemented?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQytu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Microsoft MVP on the Technet social thread you posted suggested that it's gettable via the Azure REST API.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9f946fc2-634d-4e17-949e-78c82c80c241/how-to-retrieve-the-size-of-the-recovery-services-backup-storage-vault-in-azure-powershell?forum=windowsazuredata

Have you looked through that documentation to see what options are available?

If it's available there, you could use the `Invoke-RestMethod` to do a GET to the endpoint that contains the information you're after

Comment: Thanks, trebleCode! I am reviewing that documentation right now.